# Need to give permission to user through role

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to write script in which I have create login and user, and give `Execute on` access to this USER to execute only single store procedure `SP_SELECTDEPT` but not directly only through `role`. So this way user will be having access to execute only this store procedure but it is not working.

so far I have done.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
USE master
CREATE LOGIN QGtestlogin WITH PASSWORD = 'test123', CHECK_POLICY=off
GO
USE DEPT
CREATE USER QGtestlogin FOR LOGIN QGtestlogin
go

CREATE ROLE QGtestrole AUTHORIZATION QGtestlogin
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON SP_SELECTDEPT TO QGtestrole
go

if @@ERROR > 0 
begin 
rollback transaction 
end 
else begin 
commit transaction 
end
```

But when I login with this newly created user it is not even showing the store procedure to execute.

NOTE: 
I have added the user to role member using sp_addrolemember

```
exec sp_addrolemember 'QGtestrole','QGtestlogin'
```

but still getting error:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure SP_SELECTDEPT, Line 14
The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'Dept', database 'DEPT', schema 'dbo'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be problem with SQLEXPRESS edition, When I run the same code on my actual development database they get executed and QGtestlogin able to execute the Store Procedure.